# Filter result based different conditions for different column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to find the person that rates the lowest with their average score when the following criteria are met:

1. More than 2 total reviews
2. More than 3 items reviewed

| People | score | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1.0 | a |
| Mary | 2.0 | a |
| Jack | 1.5 | b |
| Jack | 3.0 | a |
| Jack | 4.1 | b |
| Kate | 0.8 | a |

I wrote code like this

```
df %>%
  group_by(people) %>%
  mutate(na = n()) %>%
  filter(na > 2)

df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  mutate(nb = n()) %>%
  filter(nb > 60)

df %>%
group_by(people) %>%
mutate(meanscore = mean(score))
```

I don't know how to merge/ mix the result. Also, I think I didn't write it down.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try like this:**

```
people <- c('Mary', 'Mary', rep('Jack', 3), 'Kate')
score <- c(1, 2, 1.5, 3, 4.1, 0.8)
item <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a')

df <- cbind.data.frame(people, score, item)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(people) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2, length(unique(item)) > 3) %>% 
  summarise(AVG_SCORE = mean(score)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(AVG_SCORE == min(AVG_SCORE))

## n() for number of rows i.e number of reviews
## length(unique(item)) for number of unique items. 
## Then ungroup
## Then filter for the lowest average score

df2
```

Comment: Thannks for your reply!!!! Actually, this question has 3 conditions: 1. rate lowest average score; 2 made more than 2 total reviews; 3 made more than 3 items reviewed. Then I need to find the person who meets ALL these three requirements.

Comment: Seems your code works!!!!!! Appreciate!!! While may I ask 'length(unique(item)) > 3)', do this part means 【count the amount by item and then filter amount > 3】?Thank you!!!!

Comment: unique() gives you the "unique" individual elements of a vector, e.g. c(a, a, b, a, b, c) will result in a, b, c. length() gives you the length of a vector, thus length(a,b,c) = 3. With ?function you can access the built-in help of R to read up on the different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully clear on what you want to do, but given your code and question how to merge, the following might get you going.

```
# test data frame
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~People, ~score, ~item,
   "Mary",      1,   "a",
   "Mary",      2,   "a",
   "Jack",    1.5,   "b",
   "Jack",      3,   "a",
   "Jack",    4.1,   "b",
   "Kate",    0.8,   "a"
  )

# counting occurrence
> df %>%
     group_by(item) %>%
     mutate(nb = n())
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   item [2]
  People score item     nb
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1 Mary     1   a         4
2 Mary     2   a         4
3 Jack     1.5 b         2
4 Jack     3   a         4
5 Jack     4.1 b         2
6 Kate     0.8 a         4
```

Please note that this results in a "grouped" dataframe. You can `ungroup()`.

You can also use the built in `count()`:

```
item_count <- df %>% count(item)
item_count
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  item      n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         4
2 b         2
```

Using the `{tidyverse}` you merge dataframes with the `xxx_joint()`. Here we use `left_join()`:

```
df <- df %>% left_join(item_count, by = "item")
df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  People score item      n
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1 Mary     1   a         4
2 Mary     2   a         4
3 Jack     1.5 b         2
4 Jack     3   a         4
5 Jack     4.1 b         2
6 Kate     0.8 a         4
```

Now you can apply your filtering based on the `people` grouping.

```
df %>% group_by(People) %>% summarise(reviews = n(), mean_score = mean(score))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  People reviews mean_score
  <chr>    <int>      <dbl>
1 Jack         3       2.87
2 Kate         1       0.8 
3 Mary         2       1.5 

df %>% group_by(People) %>% summarise(reviews = n(), mean_score = mean(score)) %>% filter(reviews >= 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  People reviews mean_score
  <chr>    <int>      <dbl>
1 Jack         3       2.87
2 Mary         2       1.5
```

Note: typically you use `summarise()` for aggregating a row per group individual.
Compare this to your original use of `group_by()` and `mutate()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! Actually, this question has 3 conditions: 1. rate lowest average score; 2 made more than 2 total reviews; 3 made more than 3 items reviewed. Then I need to find the person who meets ALL these three requirements.

Comment: You will find many friends on here, if you provide a reproducible example that meets your problem. Think about how you construct your data frame that includes the criteria. For a start, follow up on your initial idea of constructing separate data frames answering to the different conditions. Then merge them with a `join` and filter for the cut-offs you have.

Comment: Thank you so much Ray and wish you a nice day!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

With this fake dataset `df`:

```
   People score item
1    Mary   1.0    a
2    Kate   4.0    c
3    Jack   1.5    b
4    Jack   3.0    a
5    Jack   4.1    b
6    Kate   0.8    b
7    Mary   1.0    c
8    Mary   1.0    b
9    Jack   1.5    c
10   Mary   3.0    d
11   Jack   4.1    b
12   Kate   0.8    a
```

```
df <- structure(list(People = c("Mary", "Kate", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", 
"Kate", "Mary", "Mary", "Jack", "Mary", "Jack", "Kate"), score = c(1, 
4, 1.5, 3, 4.1, 0.8, 1, 1, 1.5, 3, 4.1, 0.8), item = c("a", "c", 
"b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "b", "c", "d", "b", "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(People) %>% 
    summarise(avg_score = mean(score), 
              Total_Review = n(), 
              distinct_items = n_distinct(item)) %>% 
    filter(avg_score==min(avg_score) & 
               Total_Review > 2 & 
               distinct_items > 3)
```

you get:

```
People avg_score Total_Review distinct_items
  <chr>      <dbl>        <int>          <int>
1 Mary         1.5            4              4
```

Assumptions and explanation:

1. `Total_Review` is `n()` after `group_by(People)`
2. items are distinct: therefore a,b,a = 2 or a,b,a,a,b,c = 3

If these assumptions are correct:
We can apply `summarise` with the functions: `mean`, `n` and `n_distinct`
then we can apply the `filter` logic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! It's so clear and understandable